# android notification listener and google maps

Tags: android, notifications, listener

how can i retrieve the information in the green box from google maps navigation?
I already tried it with the notification listener service as described here:
https://yuks.me/blog/implement-android-notification-listener

But i just get the stuff from mail, whatsapp and even the screenshot notification.

[image]

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Any news on that?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem...